# How to merge transform property of two classes?

Tags: html, css

Here's the issue:

[image]

Here's my **HTML** and **CSS**:

```css
.page-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.vertical-align {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.horizontal-align {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="page-content">
  <div class="vertical-align horizontal-align">
    <div class="row">
      <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the image, the property transform of `.vertical-align` is overrided.

How can I merge the transform properties of `.vertical-align` **AND** `.horizontal-align`?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: @SankarshMakam done!

Comment: transform:translateY(-50%) !important will work in this case

Comment: But if I do this @NagaSaiA, the translateX will be overrided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define one transform property with both translates like so:

```
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
```

But I don't think you can do any more than that. There can only be one transform property.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So I guess, I could create a third class like `.center-align` for exemple, and It will do the work.

Comment: You could also do shorthand for both classes - `transform: translate( X, Y)`

Comment: Ah too late. Your answer was quicker and more condensed!

Answer (score 1):

You can combine transformations like:

```
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
```

Here is the code:

```css
.vertical-align { 
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); 
}

.horizontal-align {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); 
}

div.page-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-content">
<div class="vertical-align horizontal-align">

<div class="row">
<h1>
test
</h1>
</div>

<div class="row">
<h1>
test
</h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4xhqu04x/1/).